# I want to convert a binary numpy.ndarray to a list of lists python?

Tags: python

Hi there I need to convert a binary "numpy.ndarray" to a list of lists as the example below :

```
Matrix:
[[  #   0  1  2  3  4]
 [  0   1  0  1  0  1]
 [  1   0  0  1  1  1]
 [  2   1  0  1  1  0]
 [  3   0  0  1  0  1]
 [  4   1  1  0  0  1]
 [  5   1  0  1  1  1]
 [  6   0  0  1  0  1]]
```

```
List:
[[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[0,2,3],[2,4],[0,1,4],[0,2,3,4],[2,4]]
```

Thx in adavance

Comment: What's the logic you are using to generate the `list`?

Comment: @Equinox  if the value is 1, put his index in the final list E.g. the first row: [1  0  1  0  1] becomes [0, 2, 4]. A reproducible example would help greatly...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a small example showing the solution

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[  0 , 1,  0 , 1 , 0 , 1],
              [  1 ,  0 , 0,  1 , 1,  1],
              [  2  , 1 , 0  ,1 , 1,  0],
              [  3 ,  0 , 0  ,1,  0 , 1],
              [  4 ,  1,  1 , 0 , 0 , 1],
              [  5 ,  1  ,0 , 1,  1  ,1],
              [  6 ,  0 , 0,  1 , 0 , 1]])

out = []
for row in x:
  out.extend([np.where(row[1:]==1)[0].tolist()])

print(out)
```